# Replace a string in file

Tags: perl

My file is like this

```
DIV=25
FACILITY=11111
```

and I want to use Perl to replace DIV=25 into DIV=30. Below is my script to do it, but the output of the file is DIV=3030

```
open( IN_IOE, $FILE_NAME ) || die "Cannot open file";
my @line_ioe = <IN_IOE>;
close(IN_IOE);
chomp @line_ioe;

foreach $_ ( @line_ioe ) {
    s/DIV=/DIV=30/
}

open( OUT, ">test.txt" );
foreach $_ (@line_ioe) {
    print OUT "$_ \n";
}
close(OUT);
```

The output of my file is

```
DIV=3030
FACILITY=11111
```

Can anyone please show me how to replace that line in file with Perl, and point out where I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple lines with different numeric numbers (i.e. DIV=25, DIV =31, DIV=21) you could do following.

```
s/DIV=\d+/DIV=25/g
```

here \d is to replace any digits and 'g' to perform this globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in one line of Perl at the command line:

```
perl -pi -e 's/DIV=25/DIV=30/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show certainly didn't change `DIV=30` into `DIV=3030`. It didn't do anything at all because you have opened your output file for input

This line

```
open( OUT, "<test.txt");
```

should look like this

```
open OUT, '>', 'test.txt' or die $!;
```

Also, if you want to replace `DIV=30` with `DIV=25` then you need to write that. I think it's clear that the substitution

```
s/DIV=/DIV=25/
```

will change `DIV=30` into `DIV=2530`. Use this instead

```
s/DIV=30/DIV=25/
```

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. But, the output of my code is DIV=3030

Comment: The reason being is my file contains a lot DIV=25, DIV =31, DIV=21. But, I want them to be changed into DIV=30 in general

Comment: You shouldn't *type* your code into Stack Overflow. You must copy and paste it directly from the file you have run that isn't working. There's no way that code will produce `DIV=3030` from that data.

Comment: And again, it was my typo. And, I just fixed it. I apologized for it.